# Does a mutex guarantee visibility (GLib)?

Tags: c, concurrency, mutex, glib

I'm using Glib's mutex utilities to handle concurrency. Is it guaranteed that the updated version of a modified variable will be visible to any other thread after unlocking a mutex?
Do these threads have to acquire a lock on the mutex as well in order to read it safely?

```
GStaticMutex mutex;
int value;

void init() {
  g_static_mutex_init(&mutex);
  value = 0;
}

void changeValue() {
  g_static_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  value = generateRandomNumber();
  g_static_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of a mutex. Without this, mutexes would be useless. A mutex is always a full memory barrier.

Comment: In my understanding mutual exclusion (mutex) and visibility are separate things. So it would make some sense. Maybe post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The only (or at least main) reason mutual exclusion is useful is to synchronize data access. If it didn't do that, I can't think of many practical uses...

Comment: You could use a mutex without implicit memory barrier, to safely access a resource like an IO device. But never mind, I just wanted to know if that's always the case and apparently it is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work by the book, and let the smart people who implemented the mutex worry about visibility and barriers. The book says a mutex should be held both when reading and when writing.

The CPU can rearrange reads, and does this a lot. It helps reduce the penalty of cache misses, because you start to fetch the data a while before it's actually needed.
So if you read a variable after another CPU wrote it and released the lock, the read may actually be performed before these things happen.
The mutex serves as a memory barrier, preventing this problem (and others).

Answer (score 0):

The `mutex` object should only be read through the `g_static_mutex_*` functions. If you want to know if you can acquire the mutex you can use this function:

```
g_static_mutex_trylock
```

On the linkage of the identifier, it follows the same rules as with any other C identifier: it depends in which scope it is declared and if some storage class specifier (e. g., `static` or `extern`) is specified.

Comment: My question relates to memory visibility, I think you misunderstood it

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the answer. Gthread is a wrapper around pthread (according to http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/3/topics/425) and pthreads seem to implement a memory barrier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208060/does-guarding-a-variable-with-a-pthread-mutex-guarantee-its-also-not-cached)
But I'm uncertain if it is necessary to use the mutex read the value.