# Do I have to mark complex types as `volatile` if I am locking around the variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I'm using `pthread_mutex_t` locks to "lock around" a complex typed variable a (`std::list`).  I say "lock around" because `pthread_mutex_lock()` doesn't use the actual the `std::list` variable [as C#'s `lock` does](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/volatility.shtml).  So the `std::list` object has no idea it is being locked for access.

So I really don't know the answer to 2 questions:

1)  Does marking a complex type as `volatile` (other than `int`, `float` etc) have any effect in C++?  I am not sure since the above linked article lists (**which for C#**) only the primitive types and reference types as capable of being marked `volatile`.

2)  Do I need to mark C++ complex types as `volatile` as long as I am manually locking them?

Comment: `volatile` simply means that access to this variable is observable and cannot be optimized away, IIRC.  It does not mean thread safe, synchronized, or whatever else.  Some implementations have implementation specific meanings attached to it.  C++11 adds some threading and sychronization support to the language, prior to that it was ad hoc and library specific.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2484980/335858, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4557979/335858. Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3208060/335858

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that a variable might be changing via some mechanism outside of the current thread and so it shouldn't optimize away seemingly redundant accesses. It means nothing more, although some compilers may give it additional meaning - the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler has [this to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Although the processor does not reorder un-cacheable memory accesses, un-cacheable variables must be marked as volatile to guarantee that the compiler does not reorder the memory accesses.

The mutex code will probably provide the necessary [memory fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#Multithreaded_programming_and_memory_visibility) to ensure that the reads and writes to the protected variable don't extend beyond the bounds of the mutex, so I'd say that marking it `volatile` would not be necessary - if you've properly implemented the mutex there is no chance that another thread could try to access it.