# Why isn't pthread_cond_signal() being called?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, conditional-variable

So I am trying to understand `pthread_cond_t` variables, but the problem is often sometimes `pthread_cond_signal()/pthread_cond_broadcast()` doesn't work and the sleeping threads are not woken up, leading to a deadlock in my code.
Is there a problem in code? What is the better/best way to use condition variables?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cv;
int count = 0;
void* routine(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(count!=5) pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lock);
    printf("count value is : %d\n", count);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void* routine2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        count++;
        printf("%d\n",count);
        if(count == 5) pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
int main(){

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv,NULL);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,&routine,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,&routine2,NULL);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cv);
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? What does it do?

Comment: Does `routine2` ever release the mutex while `count` is 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're basing your logic on variables that can change between the time you read the variable and the time that you test the value.

In this code:

```
    while(count!=5) pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lock);
```

If `routine()` is called first this implicitly means that `count` is 0 (because `routine2()` is the only function that changes `count`, and does not have the lock).  `routine()` will call `pthread_cond_wait` which will release the mutex lock and then block until the condition is signaled.  Note that it also must be able to obtain the mutex lock before it finishes (i.e just the signal alone isn't sufficient).  From [pthread_cond_wait](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html)

> Upon successful return, the mutex has been locked and is owned by the
> calling thread

If `routine2()` gets the lock first it will iterate until `count` is 5 and then call `pthread_cond_signal`.  This will not however let `routine()` continue because the lock is not released at the same time.  It will continue iterating through the loop and immediately increment `count` to 6, *before* `routine()` ever gets the chance to read from the `count` variable.  As `count` cannot possibly be 5 at the time `routine()` resumes, is will deadlock (get stuck doing the above line forever).

It might seem like you could avoid this by simply not obtaining the lock with `routine2()`:

```
void* routine2(){
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        count++;
        printf("%d\n",count);
        if(count == 5) {
            pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
        }
    }
}
```

However there are also problems with this, as there is no guarantee that `count` will be 5 when `routine()` is read it as there is nothing stopping `routine2()` from continuing to process.  If that happens `routine()` will again deadlock as count will have been incremented above 5.  This is also unadvisable as accessing a shared variable from more than one thread at a time is classified as nondeterministic behavior.

The change below resolves the issue with a minimal amount of changes.  The one major change is to only wait if `count` is less than 5 (if it's 5 or more the signal was already sent).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cv;
int count = 0;
void* routine(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if (count < 5) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lock);
        printf("routine: got signal (%d)\n", count);
    } else {
        printf("routine: signal already sent\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void* routine2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        count++;
        printf("%d\n",count);
        if(count == 5) pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv,NULL);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,&routine,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,&routine2,NULL);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cv);
}
```

This [OnlineGDB snippet](https://onlinegdb.com/c4ijeftpR) demonstrates the potential for deadlock.

Comment: They *cannot* solve the problem by avoiding taking the lock in `routine2()`.  That would produce a data race involving variable `count`, yielding undefined behavior.  It is not unlikely that the resulting UB would manifest in much the same way as the program's current behavior.  Inasmuch as you also note other problems with that, it's unclear why you even bring it up.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the "other problems" are literally a race condition, you're making exactly the same point using different language.

Comment: Well, that's not at all how your prose reads, and the question remains: why even bring it up, if it's not something the OP should consider doing?

Comment: Because they should know that it's something they should not consider doing.  But yes, the prose could more explicitly say that.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the condition variables and mutex correctly but the algorithm is failing. There are two conditions here:

1. *t1* must be woken up once *count* is equal to 5;
2. When *count* is equal to 5, it must not be changed until *t1* is woken up.

Your algorithm is missing the second condition in *t2*. To make it, set a variable named *t1_woken_up* to indicate that *t1* has been woken up to display the value of *counter* equal to 5.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_cond_t cv;
int count = 0;
int t1_woken_up = 0;

void* routine(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while(count!=5) pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lock);
    printf("t1: count value is %d\n", count);
    printf("t1: Waking up t2\n");
    t1_woken_up = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void* routine2(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        count++;
        printf("t2: %d\n",count);
        if(count == 5) {
          printf("t2: Waking up t1\n");
          pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
          while (!t1_woken_up) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lock);
          }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main(){

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cv,NULL);
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,&routine,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,&routine2,NULL);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cv);
}
```

Example of execution:

```
$ gcc t.c -o t -lpthread
$ ./t
t2: 1
t2: 2
t2: 3
t2: 4
t2: 5
t2: Waking up t1
t1: count value is 5
t1: Waking up t2
t2: 6
t2: 7
```

**NB**: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172/using-c-pthreads-do-shared-variables-need-to-be-volatile) and the underlying comments, it is not necessary (better to say "not advised") to set the "volatile" attribute for the shared variables (i.e. the *count* and *t1_woken_up* variables).

Comment: Refer to [Using C/Pthreads: do shared variables need to be volatile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172/using-c-pthreads-do-shared-variables-need-to-be-volatile)  (Answer: **no**.)  From one of the answers: "The use of `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient. It's not necessary because the proper synchronization primitives are sufficient. It's not sufficient because it only disables some optimizations, not all of the ones that might bite you."

Comment: Thank you for the information @JohnBollinger. But reading the link it is not very clear how the compiler knows that the optimization are not applied in that case. I agree with the fact that volatile is not destined to synchronization but we must guarantee that the function reading it will get an up to date version of the variable when it reads it once it gets the lock. And if it is not volatile, the compiler may optimize it?

Comment: A C implementation that provides conforming pthreads support must avoid performing inappropriate optimizations in semantically correct pthreads programs, and pthreads does not require shared variables to be `volatile` for semantic correctness.  How a compiler deals with that is its concern, but this does underscore the fact that pthreads is more than just a library.  You might need to give the compiler a command-line option, such as GCC's `-pthread`, but you do not need to declare shared variables `volatile`, at least not for that reason.

Comment: OK I will update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_cond_wait(cv, mutex)` cannot return successfully unless it can obtain the *mutex*.

However, your waiting thread (*t1*) will never see the condition it is waiting for (*count == 5*), because the acting/signaling thread (*t2*) never releases the lock while the condition is true.  Thus, *t1* will go right back to waiting.

```
time   t1           t2            count
----   ---------    -----------   -----
  a     wait...     lock(mutex)    0
  b     wait...      count++       1
  c     wait...      count++       2
     >>>>>several more loops<<<<<<
  f     wait...      count++       5
  g     wait...      signal()      5
  h     wait...      count++       6
  i     wait...      count++       7
  j    (AWAKENED)   unlock(mutex)  7
  k    count != 5?     -           7
  l     wait...        -           7
```

(The above time table assumes that *t1* "goes first," which is not guaranteed.  If *t2* goes first and obtains the lock first, the table is similar except that *t1* is stuck in its initial call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` until *t2* increments *count* to 7 and then terminates.)